# Does anyone know how I can change H1 and H2 tags in Magento 1.9 on the product and category pages?

Tags: magento-1.9

I understand the H1 pull through from the meta title but would like to tweak it and add H2.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the corresponding templates (depends on your theme and other customizations) and simply apply your changes there.